# Condicionais para verificação

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou Criando um arquivo `js` com um `jquery`.
Neste arquivo preciso fazer uma condicional ou várias condicionais que verificam uma certa quantidade de números.
Se a variável `x` for um dos números `1,3,5,6,7,9,10`, deve-se mostrar a palavra *Sim*, mas se os números forem `2,4,8,11,12,17`, deve-se mostrar a palavra *nâo*.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: São exatamente esses números que vão mostrar "Sim" e "Não" ou tem algum significado por trás dos números? E também, por que usar jQuery para comparar números? Não poderia ser feito em javascript puro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) do jQuery

```js
var sim = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10];
var nao = [2, 4, 8, 11, 12, 17];

var x = 2;

if ($.inArray(x, sim) != -1) {
  document.write('sim');  
} else if ($.inArray(x, nao) != -1) {
  document.write('nao');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), não precisa de jQuery.
Se vai repetir esta verificação várias vezes pode fazer uma função para isto.

Sugiro guardar esses numeros em arrays:

```
var numerosA = [1,3,5,6,7,9,10];
var numerosB = [2,4,8,11,12,17];
```

e depois verificar o novo numero com esses:

```
numerosA.indexOf(1) != -1 // true
numerosA.indexOf(2) != -1 // false
numerosB.indexOf(1) != -1 // false
numerosB.indexOf(2) != -1 // true
```

O [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) dá a posição desse numero dentro da array. Se o numero não existir na array vai dar `-1`.

**Pode também usar um ternário para isto.** Nesse caso podeia fazer:

```
var resultado = numerosA.indexOf(seuNumero) != -1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não';
```

**Exemplo aplicado a uma função**, neste exemplo dando uma terceira resposta para casos erróneos:

```js
var numerosA = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10];
var numerosB = [2, 4, 8, 11, 12, 17];

function verificar(nr) {
    if (numerosA.indexOf(nr) != -1) return 'Sim!';
    else if (numerosB.indexOf(nr) != -1) return 'Não!';

    return 'Não existe em nenhuma...';
}

alert(verificar(1)); // Sim!
alert(verificar(2)); // Não!
alert(verificar(500)); // Não existe em nenhuma...
```

Comment: Boa resposta. Usar jQuery.inArray() pra uma coisa simples me pareceu matar formiga com bala de canhão.

Answer (score 1):

Se você preferir um solução em JQuery, você pode usar [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

```
if ($.inArray(x, [1,3,5,6,7,9,10]) !== -1){
    console.log('Sim');
}else if($.inArray(x, [2,4,8,11,12,17]) !== -1){
    console.log('Não');
}
```